# Complex nested array of object get record from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

in project it has following complex format of document in mongodb

```
{
    _id: class_1,
    students:[
        {
            _id: student_1,
            questions: [
                {
                    _id: s1q1,
                    answers:[
                        {
                            _id: s1q1a1,

                        },
                        {
                            _id: s1q1a2,

                        },
                        {
                            _id: s1q1a3,

                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    _id: s1q2,
                    answers:[
                        {
                            _id: s1q2a1,

                        },
                        {
                            _id: s1q2a2,

                        },
                        {
                            _id: s1q2a3,

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: student_2,
            questions: [
                {
                    _id: s2q1,
                    answers:[
                        {
                            _id: s2q1a1,

                        },
                        {
                            _id: s2q1a2,

                        },
                        {
                            _id: s2q1a3,

                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    _id: s2q2,
                    answers:[
                        {
                            _id: s2q2a1,

                        },
                        {
                            _id: s2q2a2,

                        },
                        {
                            _id: s2q2a3,

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried lot with aggregation but unable to get response as following

```
{
    _id: class_1,
    students:[
        {
            _id: student_1,
            questions: [
                {
                    _id: s1q1,
                    answers:[
                        {
                            _id: s1q1a1,

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

the query is like `db.collection.find({students.questions.answers._id:s1q1a1})`

if I query like above it returns get all child elements as well, so how to get only selected object with keeping nesting hierarchy?

I also tried with aggregation it gives me result till second hierarchy after it unable to filter because of mongo errors.

Comment: Use `$elemMatch` in either query or projection

Comment: You can also use mongodB projections , [this](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp) might help

Comment: @AliHussam $elemMatch result give whole array, instead only object needed

Comment: Oh since you have nested array `$elemMatch` might not work for you, you may need to write aggregate for this. Let me try as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I did this using aggregation. Also this might not be the best way to achieve the desired result but it will work

https://mongoplayground.net/p/WQGWuZKh2zQ